# "Warning! Secondary partition overlaps the last partition by x blocks" in gdisk, is it safe to use gdisk here?

Tags: hard-disk, gpt, mbr

I'm trying to convert my hard drive from MBR to GPT using `gdisk`. When I run `sudo gdisk /deve/disk1s4` I get this:

```
Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
2032668853 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
```

Does this mean that it's unsafe to change my HDD to GPT?

Comment: Is `/dev/disk1s4` the entire disk drive or just one partition of it?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That's one partition, (I have solved this issue now).

Comment: @displayname Would you mind answering your own question if you've solved it?

Comment: @BosseKlykken, I always do that, the problem is I didn't do anything differently, it just disappeared.

Comment: very odd to "just disappear". I'm facing the same problem now. I have an SSD of 480 Gb that is my sda. My 2Tb HDD is my sdb. I've changed sda's to GPT successfully through this method, but when I try to change sdb as well it throws me this exact warning. 33 blocks

Answer (score 21):

From what I just found out, it may be unsafe. I was getting this same error

> *************************************************************** Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory.
>   THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by typing 'q' if you
>   don't want to convert your MBR partitions to GPT format!
>
> ---
>
> Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by 33
>   blocks! You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another
>   utility.

According to [THIS](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/1q9p1l/converting_mbr_to_gpt_delete_boot_partition/cdaompx) link, *zman0900* says:

> GPT writes its partition table to both ends of the disk, unlike MBR
>   which only uses the beginning. So you will need to shrink your last
>   partition by at least 33 blocks (probably 16,896 bytes, assuming 512
>   byte blocks). If you have or can install gparted, that makes it very
>   easy to do. If boot is the last partition on the drive, then that is
>   the one to shrink.

I was getting this error because my last partition did not leave any space after it. All I had to do was shrink the partition from the rightmost side a little bit (3Mb but could be less), and the result was the following:

[image: Gparted screenshot]

When I ran `gdisk` afterwards no warning was thrown.

Comment: @DisplayName: This answer actually seems to correctly answer the question (for me, too). Can you mark this as solution, please, if it also answers your question?